# How to retrieve memory occupied each application in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

i had stuck at the point.i need to retrieve memory occupied by iphone inbuilt application like music,photo,movies,application etc...any one have idea please let me know.

like display detail like same.
[How to get Storage Size of Applications programmatically in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603776/how-to-get-storage-size-of-applications-programatically-in-iphone)

so please help me

Comment: I doubt there is a legitimate way to get this information.  Applications are not allowed to look at info about other apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <mach/mach.h>    
void report_memory(void) 
{
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                             TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                             (task_info_t)&info,
                             &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) 
    {
         NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
    }
}
```

you can see the size of memory in bytes

Comment: you can see the size of memory in bytes

Comment: However, there is no legitimate way to split this among various apps.

Comment: @Pavi jay No special headers included, seriously ? What's your idea of how it works then ?

Comment: can i have detail like same.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603776/how-to-get-storage-size-of-applications-programatically-in-iphone

Comment: There is also a field in the structure info.virtual_size which will give you the number of bytes available virtual memory (or memory allocated to your application as potential virtual memory in any event). The code that pgb links to will give you the amount of memory available to the device and what type of memory it is

Comment: or see that link http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Determining_Available_Memory.20081203.html it may help you. if it help please click on up button